# How to get CPU %user %system in FreeBSD without using top?

Tags: unix, cpu, freebsd, utilization

Is there any other FreeBSD command besides "top" which can be used to get the following values?

CPU:     % user,     % nice,     % system,     % interrupt,     % idle

My problem to be specific is that these values do not get updated by just "top" but require "top -d 2" and this command does not work in the current framework I'm working with.

Comment: The `systat(1)` command might be useful.

Comment: w shows some system stats.  If you can't use parameters, consider running a script that can use the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[iostat(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iostat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) shows CPU statistics:

```
   us      % of cpu time in user mode
   ni      % of cpu time in user mode running niced processes
   sy      % of cpu time in system mode
   in      % of cpu time in interrupt mode
   id      % of cpu time in idle mode
```